# SharePoint Overflow joins the Stack Exchange 2.0 family

Tags: discussion

**SharePoint Overflow users, welcome to Stack Exchange 2.0**

The SharePoint Overflow site has been converted into the Stack Exchange 2.0 family of sites.  A few things may look a little bit weird; here's why:

Users have been imported from the old site.  However, **for the first couple of weeks, we are starting with a clean slate for posts, tags, and reputation**.  We have learned from previous imports that the community needs to work together to build this site.  This means looking at what tags should be on the site, where to draw the line on what types of questions are on-topic vs off-topic, and the other [7 essential meta questions every site should ask](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/).  If existing content is immediately imported, it is much more difficult to see the tiny details that can make a huge difference in a site's success.

The posts from SharePoint Overflow are not completely gone!  At first, though, you should focus on building this community.  After that, we'll appoint [Pro Tempore Moderators](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) to help lead the site.  Once this happens, we will re-add some of the best quality content from the old site.  Users that own these posts will have their rep (and applicable badges) restored.

In the meantime, you can [download the SharePoint Overflow data dump](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/042011%20SharePoint%20Overflow.zip) to access the old content if needed.

Comment: Yay! We made it!

Comment: I'm happy for the move! We will now attract a bunch more users. There's quite a bit of questions on serverfault and stackoverflow that directly pertain to SharePoint.

Comment: "Once this happens, we will re-add some of the best quality content from the old site" How is this determined?

Comment: I wonder how you guys are going to achieve that import. Btw could you document the migration so that others can learn from your successes?

Comment: @Muhimbi: Thanks for asking this, I've made it it's own [meta question](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20/).

Answer (score 4):

Does this mean no beta badges for folks?

Comment: The private beta phase was skipped since this was an import of an existing community so no beta badges are awarded.

Comment: @Geoff, as of today, there is 1 person with the 'enthusiast' badge already. That requires 30 days of logging into the site. I logged in the first day it was open for the public and it shows 3 days for me. What gives? How can folks have more history than the rest of the world has?

Comment: user history was carried over from the existing sharepoint overflow.

Answer (score 4):

many useful SharePoint google links currently link to the old site, which are now all 404'ing - would be a shame to lose them.

suggest some compromise where top... 100? google 404 links to old SharePoint overflow are maintained while we transition.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to mention that the old site looked better.

Please tell me if there is anyway a user can change the look back to what it was before?

Comment: We are still in beta stage. There will be a new theme once we get closer to launch. Please see question 5 of the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) for more info.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the reply. I must be honest the StackExchange group design logo seems faded, and the buttons hand drawn. I think this is to make the whole site seem less formal or modern, but the best looking sites were always Stackoverflow (clean and crisp) and the old SharepointOverflow looked like a brother / sister site also crisp just different colors.

Comment: I think the aim is for it to look like a sketchpad, to represent that the site is still in beta, and yet to be defined.