# SharePoint questions on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Great job with the site! I think my F5 key is almost worn out...

I've read the [welcome message](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family) about starting with a clean slate. I'm assuming this also applies to the [SharePoint questions on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sharepoint). I'm also assuming we want ALL SharePoint questions to be [asked here instead of on SO](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/when-should-a-question-be-posted-on-sharepoint-overflow-instead-of-stackoverflow).

The existing sharepointoverflow.com site now redirects to sharepoint.stackexchange.com. What about the questions being asked on StackOverflow? Can we lock the tags? Or redirect? Announcement on SO?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*If it's a programming question*, there's no reason why it can't be asked on Stack Overflow. There is some overlap; really, it's up to the user asking the question where they want to ask it.

If you see a SharePoint-related (**but *not* programming-related**) question asked on Stack Overflow, flag it for moderator attention and request that it be migrated. It's also polite in that case to leave a comment noting that, while off-topic for SO, the question would be welcome here - you may find the user more than willing to re-ask the question here himself, saving everyone a lot of trouble.

Finally, if you happen to see a SharePoint question on SO that's just not getting the attention it needs, suggesting to the author that he ask it here will help you to promote the site...

Comment: +1 Good point about the overlap. I think we need to start being more aggressive with this on SO for the non-programming related questions.

Comment: @Kit: provided they're truly off-topic on SO, go for it. Better they get an answer *somewhere*... Be wary of suggesting that older questions get migrated though, at least during the beta period here.

Comment: Bit puzzled - what if it is programming-related and about SharePoint? E.g. Using the SharePoint Object Model, or CAML? Presumably that would be best dealt with in one place. So, in this case, does 'programming related' really mean 'related to programming generally'?

Comment: @Andy: quick answer is, a programming-related question involves *code*. The scope of SO is a bit broader than this, but when deciding between two, overlapping sites this is a pretty good starting metric. Once you're past that... [A question on the SharePoint object model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645253/) would probably be *better off* here, but wouldn't necessarily need to be migrated if asked on SO. [A question on some API or language construct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5634200) by a user who just happens to be working with SharePoint probably shouldn't be here at all.

Comment: Agree with everything but the prasing "re-ask". Why would we need cross-posts? If its relevant on SO it should stay there, if its relevant on SPSE it should be moved there. Re-posting would create a redundant mess IMO

Comment: @Anders: agreed - re-asking is only appropriate if the question has been closed as off-topic (but *not* migrated) on SO. My point is simply that it's polite to leave a comment noting *why* a question is more appropriate here than on SO: that's your chance to evangelize the site to users who might be unaware of it and would find it useful.

Answer (score 7):

Can we have a button on the `This question is .. off topic` dialog on Stack Overflow (even if it's just when the question is tagged with the `sharepoint` tag)?
[image]

Comment: Looks like the answer is "No" until the site gets out of Beta: http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37/can-we-migrate-questions-over-from-so-yet

Comment: I think this will be actively harmful. There are lots of SharePoint programmers on SO and I have received answers to my questions there, while the same questions posted to SharePoint Overflow generated no activity. Actually, I'm against this site making it out of beta.

Comment: @skolima: No big deal, feel free to ask SharePoint **programming** questions on SO. All SharePoint questions are still welcome here.