# Why Aren't All Sharepoint Questions Migrated to Sharepoint SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SharePoint questions on StackOverflow?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sharepoint-questions-on-stackoverflow)

It is [my understanding](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2/sharepoint-questions-on-stackoverflow) that if a question is programming-related, it can be positively asked on Stack Overflow.  However, [ANY Sharepoint questions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1055/when-should-a-question-be-posted-on-sharepoint-overflow-instead-of-stackoverflow/1062#1062), whether about programming or not [can also be asked here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/are-programming-questions-off-topic-in-sharepoint-se).

Thus, I am led to ask my question, why is it that we don't ask and migrate ALL Sharepoint questions here?

Comment: I've always wondered this too. A lot of people will post the same question on both sites and try to get answers from either, which is definitely not ideal.

Comment: IMO, I would prefer for all SharePoint questions to be asked here.. but then again I'm biased. :P You nailed it though - since the Qs are programming related they are allowed on SO.

Comment: To whoever closed this question, I say that maybe the answers may be related, but the question is definitely NOT the same.  This question is very precise.  The "possible duplicate" is very broad and can be answered in different ways.  This question is not so permissive.  I vote to repen it on this account.  Besides, the other question does not ask directly for what this entry queries, and as such, will not get the clear answer desired by this question.

Comment: @BGM I closed the question because the questions are very similar and the answers are the same: SharePoint questions are allowed on SO and won't be migrated.

Comment: Okay, I understand, but don't agree.  The other questions were not scoped to fetch the answer I am looking for.  My question is precise and requires a precise answer.  The "possible duplicate" isn't even a question.