# What happened to my post?

Tags: discussion

[What's happending in the background when you Check-in/Publish](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/10776/whats-happending-in-the-background-when-you-check-in-publish)

Seems to be lost?

Comment: Was it posted on the old SharePointOverflow site?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the old sharepointoverflow.com was migrated to this site.  See:  [SharePoint Overflow joins the Stack Exchange 2.0 family](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family) for more details.