# Is it possible to retrieve answers from the old SharePoint Overflow?

Tags: support, answers

Not necessarily on the Q&A site here itself, just in general.

Back when SharePoint Overflow was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, I [posted a question to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716361/can-i-export-a-sharepoint-list-to-an-excel-file-subdivided-into-separate-workshee), and after some time without a solution I posted a similar inquiry SharePoint Overflow. I got my proper answer on SharePoint Overflow, and as per guidance I received on Meta Stack Overflow, I posted such on the Stack Overflow site, without being specific so as to keep the full answer on SharePoint Overflow.

Now that the Stack Exchange 1.0 site is no more, the link points to a dead destination here (though it may be populated with a completely different question in due time).

Is it possible to retrieve the original content from SharePoint Overflow, so that I may put that properly in that answer? Or is that data effectively gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that the old SharePoint Overflow has been imported in here, most answers (if not all, not sure about how thorough the import wast) are available on the site now.

So, for example, [I found mine here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/can-i-export-a-sharepoint-2007-list-to-an-excel-file-subdivided-into-separate-wor). Strangely, it appears to actually be the same old post ID as I had before, so I guess I don't have to update the URL on the Stack Overflow post anyway.

Comment: Yes, we abandoned our original plans to do a partial import.  And yes, all ids were kept.

Comment: Just spent 2 days' worth of votes picking out good answers to 'unanswered' questions to bring the % answered up from 86% to 90%, and then saw it drop to 71%! After a moment's heart attack I realised why. Panic over. :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm hoping that this answer is a joke. I've pointed people to old SharePoint Overflow posts in my blog, in discussions, in emails, etc. Are all of the old posts truly "gone"? Saying they are in an XML dump somewhere means that they are gone, IMO, and also IMO, that stinks.

Many of us worked damn hard to answer all of those questions and I know that people have and would probably still rely on them if they could get to them. If this is some sort of judgement that sites that weren't running under the SE umbrella must have inferior content, then I'm packing my bags and not using the SE family of sites anymore, and I'll tell others to do the same. We have other channels.

p.s. I was a moderator on the old SharePoint Overflow site. I also miss all of the points I earned by answering question on the old SharePoint Overflow.

Comment: It is a joke, but the joke is on us :-P . Nice to be able to go back to your SharePoint Overflow post to remember how you solved a problem - oh, wait - they deleted it all. It's all in some big file somewhere: great.  I'm annoyed, but not throwing my toys out of the pram just yet ;-)

Comment: Like we've said, we *will* be importing posts, hopefully within a couple of days.  We look at how many views questions had, how many votes, how many answers, how many votes those answers had...all to try to bring in the content that people relied on.  We absolutely recognize the old site had valuable content, and that's what we want to bring in.  In addition, all rep associated with the posts we bring in will be restored.

Comment: Rebecca: With all due respect, how can you possibly know what content has value and what doesn't? You don't have the domain expertise, we do. A question with a good answer that was viewed 5 times might have tremendous value to the next person looking for that particular answer.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson, I absolutely don't have the domain expertise, not pretending I do.  That's why view count isn't all we look at.

Comment: But "all to try to bring in the content that people relied on" can't always be measured by what you propose. Some questions/answers become more valuable over time as the product lifecycle progresses. Just because some obscure question wasn't looked at a lot in the first six months of SharePoint 2010's existence doesn't mean that it won't be critical in the next 6 months. My point is that we, the community, worked to build that content corpus and and you, the software people, are deciding how to value it. It's bass-ackwards.

Comment: Well, we are SharePoint folks, and we mostly work in a business environment where, if content goes offline for 10 minutes it's "OMG the sky is falling - your job's on the line". This attitude of "maybe it will be back next week, if we like the look of it" is quite quaint.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson, views aren't all we look at, just for that reason.  Shouldn't votes (both on a question itself and on the answers it gets) also be an indicator of what is valuable content?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Perhaps as a compromise is it possible to reimport all of the old content, but set those questions that don't meet the quality bar to Deleted? Then at least mods that have the domain knowledge can undelete if appropriate or if someone complains about a missing question?

Comment: @Rebecca - I think I've made my points. I don't believe that any algorithm that you come up with will be as effective as simply reintstating all of the old content. I feel that we ran a great site with SharePointOverflow with the efforts of many very smart people. The content that was there had value; that which didn't, we either excised or worked to clarify. Babies and bathwater come to mind.  I'm also totally certain that there are many people who get value from an answer without ever voting or commenting. Lurkers are still in the majority, IMO.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson, we're looking at what options we have.

Comment: @MarcDAnderson, we listened - you got your wish. (:

Comment: Did you add back all of the old content? That wish? :-)

Answer (score 2):

The old data was wiped, to allow the site to spend some quality time in The SE 2.0 Beta Crucible. See: [SharePoint Overflow joins the Stack Exchange 2.0 family](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/sharepoint-overflow-joins-the-stack-exchange-2-0-family)

[The best of it *will* be restored](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-does-we-will-re-add-some-of-the-best-quality-content-from-the-old-site-mea), once this *trial by fire* is over. Until then, you can [download the data dump](http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/042011%20SharePoint%20Overflow.zip), and either attack it with your favorite XML-attacking-tools, or use something like the unfortunately-named [AUBrowser](https://launchpad.net/aubrowser) to query it.

Comment: When will we be out of purgatory? :)

Comment: There's a data dump - that's really enough of it for me to be able to (eventually) dig that answer out. Excellence.

Comment: @ccomet I commend your enthusiasm, but I think you may have set the bar for "Excellence" a little low ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The data can be downloaded at http://sstatic.net/area51/datadumps/042011%20SharePoint%20Overflow.zip